# Getting Error with high_phone script on fivem

Tags: lua, fivem

Error parsing script @high_phone/server/mail.lua in resource high_phone: @high_phone/server/mail.lua:792: ')' expected (to close '(' at line 778 near 'end'

```
MySQL.Async.fetchScalar("SELECT `id` FROM phone_mail WHERE `owner` = @owner AND `subject` =     @subject ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1", {}, function(_ARG_0_)
    ({}).id = _ARG_0_
    ;({}).subject = _UPVALUE1_
    if "table" ~= type(_UPVALUE2_) or _UPVALUE2_ then
    end
    ;({}).recipients, ({})[1] = {}, _UPVALUE2_
    ;({}).address = _UPVALUE3_.address
    ;({}).name = _UPVALUE3_.name
    ;({}).sender, ({}).photo = {}, _UPVALUE3_.photo
    ;({}).content = _UPVALUE4_
    ;({}).time = _UPVALUE5_
    ;({}).attachments = _UPVALUE6_
    TriggerClientEvent("high_phone:receivedMail", _UPVALUE0_.source, {})
  end
end)
```

We tried to remove and set new ) but nothing happend so the code is back in normal condition

Comment: The first line is line778 so the last one is 792 as the error told that the problem is anywhere in it

Answer (score 0):

You open two blocks (`function(_ARG_0_)` and `if "table"  ...` but have three `ends`. Delete one.